# File-argument in libc::stat in Rust

Tags: rust, libc

I'm struggling to call `libc::stat` in Rust. I have this:

```
extern crate libc;
use std::fs::File;
use std::os::unix::prelude::*;
use std::path::Path;

fn main() {
    let p = Path::new("/");
    let f = File::open(&p).unwrap();
    let fd = f.as_raw_fd() as i8;

    unsafe {
        let mut stat: libc::stat = std::mem::zeroed();
        if libc::stat(fd, &mut stat) >= 0 {
            println!("{}", stat.st_blksize);
        }
    }
}
```

but now I receive this error: `error: mismatched types: expected *const i8, found i8`

I couldn't find any documentation on how the first argument works. Judging from the type (`i8`) I thought it must be file descriptor.

Background: I'm reading through "Advanced Programming in the UNIX Environment" and want to do some exercises in Rust instead of C.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first argument to [`stat`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat) is the file path as a C string. C strings are represented in Rust by [`CStr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ffi/struct.CStr.html) (borrowed) or [`CString`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ffi/struct.CString.html) (owned). Here is an example using `CString`:

```
extern crate libc;

use std::ffi::CString;

fn main() {
    unsafe {
        let root = CString::new("/").unwrap();
        let mut stat: libc::stat = std::mem::zeroed();
        if libc::stat(root.as_ptr(), &mut stat) >= 0 {
            println!("{}", stat.st_blksize);
        }
    }
}
```

Take a look at the [FFI chapter](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ffi.html) of the Rust Book for other information.